# How to change only specific nav active background color with condition

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

i would like to change only 1 specific nav-item to red color if it is selected which means others would be remain blue and only the the specific nav-itm's color would be change if it is selected.

The example condition would be like:

`if(this.tabid===3 && active) { background color:red; }`

```
<b-navbar-nav class="mx-auto row nav-slot-custom-bar">
                            <template v-for="(item, i) in menus">
                                <b-nav-item 
                                    :href="item.href" 
                                    class="col" 
                                    @click="changeTab(item.tabid)" 
                                    :class="{'active': selectNav == item.tabid}" 
                                    :key="i">

                                    <b-row class="text-center mb-1 nav-btm-icon" :class="{'active': selectNav == item.tabid}">
                                        <img
                                            :src="item.icon" 
                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                            class="mx-auto"
                                            style="width: 31px; height: 31px;"
                                            :class="{ 'active': selectNav == item.tabid }"
                                           
                                          
                                          
                                        />
                                    </b-row>
                                </b-nav-item>
                            </template>
                    </b-navbar-nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add conditional classes like so. And then I would just add a class with your desired properties:

```js
:class="[
 this.tabid === 3 && active ? 'be_red' : ''
]"

<style>
.be_red {
  background-color:red;
}
</style>
```